# Files renamed by Powershell code have same name, however first part of one of them is not deleted?

Tags: windows, powershell

I receive numerous files on a weekly basis which are batch saved into a folder. Before i insert them into a software for processing, i am required to remove the date aspect of the name
the files come in this format:

```
20082019AAAA

21082019AAAA
```

These files are received (for example) on the same day, and save into the same folder.

I have a simple PowerShell code which removes the date prefix of the name

```
get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(8) }
```

However, a problem arises.

If this code were to delete the first 8 characters from both files, both files would be named `AAAA`

Therefore, upon running, the files end up looking like this:

```
AAAA

21082019AAAA
```

As you can see, only for one of the files is the date prefix deleted.

How can I modify my code such that upon running it will delete the prefix, and if it finds two files with the same remaining name, it will add an `_2` or something of the sort to the files?

This will really improve efficiency as then I can point to the folder directly for auto processing.

Kind regards

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm sure there are quite a bunch of similar questions with Copy/Move/Rename increment:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\21\SO_57594000.ps1
# create some sample files in current dir
# -2..2|%{ni ('{0}AAAA.txt' -f (Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString('ddMMyyyy'))}|Out-Null
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Where-Object Name -match '^\d{8}' | ForEach-Object{
    $NewName = ($_.Name -replace '^\d{8}')
    $cnt=0
    while (Test-Path (Join-Path $_.Directory $NewName)){
       $NewName = '{0}_{1}{2}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '^\d{8}'),++$Cnt,$_.Extension
    }
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green ('Renamed {0} to {1}' -f $_.Name,$NewName)
}
```

**Edit** did a small rework with this output:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-Childitem '*.txt'

foreach( $file in $files ) {

        if( $file.Name -match '^\d{8}.+$' ) {

            $newName = $file.Name.Substring(8)

            $counter = 1
            while( Test-Path ( $newName )) {
                $newName = $newName -replace '^([^\.]+)(_\d)*\.(txt)$', ('$1_' + $counter.ToString() + '.$3')
                $counter++
            }
            Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName | Out-Null
        }
    }
```

Comment: With `.Substring(8)` you will shorten ***any*** file name not just the ones with a leading date, also file names could contain dots (even if not presented here).

Comment: Thanks guys!! These work perfectly! Going to make batch processing so much easier

Comment: If you are happy with the solution, please give an upvote, thanks